# How to use compose operator in APL?

Tags: apl, dyalog

I'm not able to understand compose operator in APL.

I have tried but precedence is the issue that I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by *compose operator* you mean `f∘g` (where `f` and `g` are [functions](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Function)) which Dyalog 18.0 renamed from the general name [Compose](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Compose) to the more specific name [Beside](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Beside). `X f∘g Y` (where `X` and `Y` are [arrays](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Array)) is equivalent to `X f g Y`, and `f∘g Y` is equivalent to `f g Y`.

`f∘g` is a [derived function](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Derived_function) and so is subject to the same [precedence](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Precedence) as all other APL functions (i.e. long right scope). The binding rules might trip you up if `g` is itself a derived function. E.g. if `f←-` and `g←+/` then `f∘g¨ (3 1 4 1 5)(2 7 1 8)` gives `¯14 ¯18` because it is the negation of the sum of each list. However, if you try to insert the definitions of `f` and `g` into `f∘g` so you have `-∘+/¨ (3 1 4 1 5)(2 7 1 8)`, you instead get `10 ¯12`. This is because `-∘+/` binds as `(-∘+)/` rather than `-∘(+/)` due to [operators](https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Operator) having long left scope.

In conclusion, try to use parentheses to clarify how you want things to bind. If this doesn't help, then amend your question with more details of what you're trying to do.

Comment: It is giving output as 10 and -12 by using compose operator

Comment: @AkshayAtanure Right, then you need to parenthesise (or name) the right operand: `-∘(+/)¨ (3 1 4 1 5)(2 7 1 8)`

Comment: Can you tell me about how to write conditional statements and functions using del operator in APL?

Comment: @AkshayAtanure Maybe, but it isn't clear to me what you mean by that. Maybe ask a new question with more detail?

Comment: I am not able to use del operator in APL. When I'm creating a new function, it is giving as syntax error.